# vuejs Out of stack space in IE11

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11, babel-polyfill

I am new to Vuejs and trying to make a small web app that can also run on IE11.
I managed to make it IE compatible with [polyfills](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#usebuiltins-usage) (.browserslistrc=IE 11).

But I notice the app is very slow in IE11 (not in Edge/Chrome) and in IE11 very often I see `SCRIPT28: Out of stack space`

Can you please give some ideas about such behaviors IE11? and is there is any solution to make it run smooth?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are recursive calls in your code, or the interpreter is overwhelmed by referencing a large amount of data, which will cause the problem. Have you tried putting polyfills references before Vuejs? If this does not work, could you please provide more details, such as [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue?